# How to rotate div 360 in 3D in Y axis?

Tags: html, css, css-animations, transformation

I'm trying to recreate the text that is rotating 3D in Y axis.

So I came up with the following and it is centered, but it does not do anything (I'm using SCSS by the way):

```
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="rotate-wrapper">
      <div>
        Rotate me
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

What could I be doing wrong? Explanations would be appreciated for purpose of learning.

Thank you in advance and will accept/upvote answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to actually make the `rotation` animation. In the site you specified, it is defined as:

```css
@-webkit-keyframes rotation {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
            transform: rotateY(0deg); }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
            transform: rotateY(180deg); }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);
            transform: rotateY(360deg); } }

@keyframes rotation {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
            transform: rotateY(0deg); }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
            transform: rotateY(180deg); }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);
            transform: rotateY(360deg); } }
```

For an explanation on how CSS animations work, see [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations).

Comment: Before I accept the answer and upvote, how can I have it switch to another text once it turns to the back? Also how can I optimize code to make more sense? I kind made guesses as I was creating the CSS, so believe it is not clean.

Comment: You would have two texts, the second one having `transform: rotateY(180deg);`. You would also make sure that they overlap. There is no "optimising" the code - it makes plenty of sense as it is.

Comment: What does `all` mean for transition and `perspective`? Also what is do the percentages, e.g. 0%, 50%, etc. represent?

Comment: also how did you obtain the `rotation` in the site specified?

Comment: [transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/transition) and [perspective](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/perspective)'s MDN articles. `all` in `transition` means that the transition will apply to all properties (you also do not need `transition` at all in this case) and `perspective`'s property is the `<length>` property; the distance from the `z` plane. The percentages are the keyframe position: `0%` is the start of the animation, `50%` is the middle and `100%` is the end.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135321/discussion-between-lemmmy-and-jo-ko).

Comment: sorry but what do you mean by distance from the `z` plane?